# cURL request in PHP with IP of Proxy list - proxy.webshare.io - Failed to connect

Tags: php, curl, proxy, ip, php-curl

i have a plan on `proxy.webshare.io`, I have a proxy list with 500 ip and i try to do a `cURL request` in **PHP** but i have this error:

**Curl error: Failed to connect to 3x.xx.xx.xxx port xxxx: Connection timed out**

I have ever this error, also if i change IP.

This is my request:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$proxy = "username:password@IP:PORT";
$url= 'https://ipinfo.io/';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_SOCKS5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);    
$response = curl_exec($ch);
echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

I'm sure the problem is not the website of request because i have this error also with different $url.
On webshare.io there are two different **Authentication Method**:

1. with username and password (is mine)
2. with ip

I don't understand where is the problem.... maybe in the request ? (ip, port, url, username, passoword are correct) or maybe in my settings profile ?

[image]

i hope someone can help me ... i'm very sad :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_PROXY, 'IP:PORT');
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, 'username:password');
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15); //timeout in seconds
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

$response = curl_exec($curl_handle);
$http_code = curl_getinfo($curl_handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($curl_handle);
```